# IEEE 754 square root with Newton-Raphson

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, numerical-methods, floating-point

I have an implementation of the `sqrt` function that uses a combination of IEEE 754, packed bitfields, and the Newton-Raphson algorithm:

`decompose.h`:

```
#ifndef DECOMPOSE_H
#define DECOMPOSE_H 1

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <float.h>

#define MANTISSA_SIZE 52
#define EXPONENT_SIZE 11
#define EXPONENT_BIAS 0x3ff
#define TYPE double
#define TYPE_MIN DBL_MIN
#define TYPE_MAX DBL_MAX
#define NAME_SFX(name) name

typedef unsigned long long mantissa;
typedef unsigned short exponent;
typedef unsigned char sign;

#include "decompose_generic.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

`decompose_generic.h`:

```
#ifndef DECOMPOSE_GENERIC_H
#define DECOMPOSE_GENERIC_H 1

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define SIGN_SIZE 1

union decompose {
    TYPE f;
    struct decompose_s {
        mantissa m:MANTISSA_SIZE;
        exponent e:EXPONENT_SIZE;
        sign s:SIGN_SIZE;
    } __attribute__((packed)) o;
};

static inline union decompose decompose(TYPE f)
{
    union decompose result;
    result.f = f;
    return result;
}

#define is_nan(x) NAME_SFX(isnan)(x)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

`sqrt.c`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "decompose.h"

TYPE NAME_SFX(sqrt)(TYPE a)
{
    TYPE result_old2 = 0;
    unsigned short c = 0;
    union decompose r = decompose(a);

    if(a < -(TYPE)0)
    {
        errno = EDOM;
        return NAME_SFX(nan)("");
    }
    if(a == (TYPE)0 || is_nan(a) || a > TYPE_MAX)
    {
        return a;
    }

    /* Divide the exponent by 2 */
    r.o.e -= EXPONENT_BIAS;
    r.o.e = (r.o.e & 1) | (r.o.e >> 1);
    r.o.e += EXPONENT_BIAS;

    /* Newton-Raphson */
    while(result_old2 != r.f)
    {
        if(c % 2 == 0) result_old2 = r.f;
        r.f -= (r.f*r.f-a)/(2*r.f);
        c++;
    }

    return r.f;
}
```

What I'm looking for:

- Are there any efficiency problems?
- Are there any accuracy problems?
- Are there any other miscellaneous things that I can improve?

As far as I've tested, this is as accurate as possible. It even matches the results from the GNU C library.

One note: This is part of a modular system. There will be a `decompose.h` for each floating point type (`float`, `double`, `long double`), and they all include `decompose_generic.h`.

I'm slightly new to this area of C (math, IEEE 754), but not so new that I'd add the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag.

Comment: It's a shame this isn't C++, where you could check that the floating-point representation matches your expectation using `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`.  I don't know of an equivalent test for C, other than separately checking all the macros in `<float.h>`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `__STDC_IEC_559__`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This answer uses pointer-casting for type-punning just to save space.  In practice keep using your union (safe in ISO C99, and in C++ as a GNU and MSVC extension) or memcpy (safe in C and C++).  This pointer-casting is only safe in MSVC, or GNU-compatible compilers with `-fno-strict-aliasing`

## Initial approximation

Packed bit fields are not only unnecessary here, they make the result worse. You do something along the lines of:

```
uint64_t i = *(uint64_t*)&f;           // double to int
i = i - (1023 << 52);                  // remove IEEE754 bias
i = i >> 1;                            // divide exponent by 2
i = i + (1023 << 52);                  // add IEEE754 bias
```

If you change the order of operations, you can handle the biasing in a single constant:

```
uint64_t i = *(uint64_t*)&f;           // double to int
i = i >> 1;                            // divide exponent by 2
i = i + (1023 << 52) - (1023 << 51);   // remove/add IEEE754 bias
```

The constant can then be simplified to:

```
uint64_t i = *(uint64_t*)&f;           // double to int
i = (i >> 1) + (1023 << 51);           // all of the above
```

Note that I didn't bother to mask when shifting, so the exponent's rightmost bit drops into the mantissa, which is shifted as well. This is a feature, not a bug. The IEEE754 formats are deliberately chosen to be monotonic when interpreted as integers, so carry-overs between exponent and mantissa are explicitly allowed.

With my approximation, the mapping is as follows (linear mapping within intervals):

```
original   number is    exponent   manitssa   orig interval
exponent  in interval   in sqrt   first bit     maps to
   0     [  1.0,  2.0 )    0         0       [  1.0,  1.5 )
   1     [  2.0,  4.0 )    0         1       [  1.5,  2.0 )
   2     [  4.0,  8.0 )    1         0       [  2.0,  3.0 )
   3     [  8.0, 16.0 )    1         1       [  3.0,  4.0 )
   4     [ 16.0, 32.0 )    2         0       [  4.0,  6.0 )
```

With your code, the mapping is (also linear within intervals):

```
original   number is    exponent  orig interval
exponent  in interval   in sqrt     maps to
   0     [  1.0,  2.0 )    0     [  1.0,  2.0 )
   1     [  2.0,  4.0 )    0     [  1.0,  2.0 )
   2     [  4.0,  8.0 )    1     [  2.0,  4.0 )
   3     [  8.0, 16.0 )    1     [  2.0,  4.0 )
   4     [ 16.0, 32.0 )    2     [  4.0,  8.0 )
```

## Newton-Raphson

Given a good approximation, Newton-Raphson doubles the number of significant digits on each iteration (quadratic convergence). The above approximation provides about 4 bits of accuracy (max error: 6% or ~1/16), so 3 Newton-Raphson iterations are required for single and 4 iterations for double precision.

The entire code could look like this:

```
float sqrtf(float x)
{
    float y = x;
    // Approximation
    uint32_t* i = (uint32_t*)&x;
    *i = (*i >> 1) + (127 << 22);
    // Newton-Raphson
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    return x;
}

double sqrt(double x)
{
    double y = x;
    // Approximation
    uint64_t* i = (uint64_t*)&x;
    *i = (*i >> 1) + (1023 << 51);
    // Newton-Raphson
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    x = (x + y/x) / 2;
    return x;
}
```

## Subnormals and other hazards

You already have special handling for `nan`, `inf`, `0` and `x < 0`, which is good, but we need to handle subnormal numbers as well. The code, both yours and mine, fails when confronted with such numbers. As a remedy, I suggest you scale subnormal numbers by `2^200` and scale the result by `2^-100`. I chose `2^200` because it safely brings all subnormals back into normal range for all precisions, including quad, but other numbers work equally well (but only powers of two retain full precision).

Also observe that my code relies on IEEE754 properties. It doesn't work for non-IEEE754 numbers, most notably x86's 80bit `extended double` format. If you want to handle such numbers, you can convert them to `float` or `double` for the approximation step and back to `extended double` for Newton-Raphson.

Comment: This won't work for 80-bit long double, which can't be represented as an integer.

Comment: Also note that this violates strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.

Comment: How many bits of accuracy does the current implementation provide?

Comment: Your approximation is off by 41% at worst, that's about 1bit. (with my approximation it's ~6%) - @JL2210

Comment: How can I have something similar to your implementation that 1) doesn't violate strict aliasing and 2) works for `long double`?

Comment: I don't think the initial approximation, the way it is now, will work for a `long double`.

Comment: `*(uint64_t*)&f` is undefined behaviour in ISO C.  It's only well-defined in MSVC or `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.  , @JL2210 used a union to type-pun because that's well-defined in ISO C99.  (But in C++ only as a GNU extension.  They should probably have used `memcpy` since they bothered to include `extern "C" {}` stuff in case it's compiled as C++)

Comment: @JL2210 and Rainer:: The other problem with 80-bit `long double` is that the leading 1 or 0 in the significand (aka mantissa) is *explicit*, not implied by the exponent field being non-zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format  So shifting a bit from the exponent into the mantissa could be a big problem, potentially creating a non-normalized value that isn't a subnormal.  I forget what x86/x87 hardware does in that case.   If you were using C++, you could use a `std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>`

Comment: @PeterCordes I should probably just remove the `extern "C"` baggage. I'm not intending for this to be compiled in C++, anyway.

Comment: @RainerP. What would you consider a "subnormal"?

Comment: @JL2210 - An [IEEE754 subnormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) is a number too small to be represented. These are encoded in a fixed-point manner and the exponent field is zeroed out and meaningless. Zero is a subnormal number.

Comment: How do I scale these?

Comment: @JL2210 - You can distinguish subnormals using `is_normal()` (similar to `is_nan()`) and scale them with an ordinary multiplication. The FPU handles all the nasty stuff.

Comment: @RainerP. You mean `isnormal`? I defined `is_nan` myself as a type-generic macro. I sadly don't have `isnormal` available anyway. I haven't gotten that far in my math implementation.

Comment: `(1023 << 52)` is UB.  Recommend `(1023ull << 52)`

Answer (score 10):

FYI, in IEEE754 `sqrt` is a "basic" operation that's **required to be correctly-rounded** (rounding error <= 0.5ulp), same as + - * /.  Hardware FPUs (I think) always provide sqrt if they provide the other operations, especially division which is [typically implemented similarly (and with similar performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642663/how-sqrt-of-gcc-works-after-compiled-which-method-of-root-is-used-newton-rap).

NR iterations each involving a division are *not* going to be faster than HW sqrt.  I think that's part of why x86's approximation instructions are for reciprocal and rsqrt, not sqrt: the Newton iteration formula for `1/sqrt(x)` doesn't involve division, so on old CPUs with very slow sqrtps  compared to mulps, it was worth using `sqrt(x) ~= x * approx_rsqrt(x)`, [optionally with a Newton iteration on the approx_rsqrt result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555260/fast-vectorized-rsqrt-and-reciprocal-with-sse-avx-depending-on-precision).  Maybe sometimes still worth doing that in a loop that does nothing else, but normally you should aim for more computational intensity (do more with your data while it's hot in registers; don't write loops that just load/sqrt/store).

IDK if it's possible for your code to converge on a value that's not the correctly-rounded result, but something you should test for by checking against the implementation's `sqrt` function.

(Call your function something else.  With GCC for example, `sqrt` is a special name unless you use `-fno-builtin-sqrt`.  Callers will inline the sqrt instruction on targets that have one, like x86 `sqrtsd`, only calling the libc function for inputs that need to set errno.  Or never if you compile with `-fno-math-errno`, always a good idea.  Math-errno is an optional feature that not all libcs support, although GNU C does.  It's a pretty bad obsolete design that [nobody should use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673825/how-to-force-gcc-to-assume-that-a-floating-point-expression-is-non-negative/57674631#57674631); that's why we have `fenv.h` to check per-thread sticky FP exception flags.)

---

#### Wrong initial guess for inputs < 1.0

> ```
>  /* Divide the exponent by 2 */
>  r.o.e -= EXPONENT_BIAS;
>  r.o.e = (r.o.e & 1) | (r.o.e >> 1);
>  r.o.e += EXPONENT_BIAS;
> ```

Your exponent bitfield type is `unsigned short`<sup>1</sup> so this is a logical right shift.

But anyway, **logical right shift is a bug in your initial approximation.**

The exponent field is a 2's complement integer (encoded with a bias, but that's just an encoding/decoding detail you already take care of).  A logical right shift of a small exponent (like for `0.0001`) will result in a large *positive* exponent from shifting in a zero.  Your initial guess for `0.0001` will be something close-ish to `DBL_MAX`, way above `1.0`.

**You need an arithmetic right shift of the exponent** to bring it closer to the middle exponent value (unbiased) `0` or (biased) `127`.  Thus bringing the magnitude of the represented value closer to `1.0`.

*Most* C implementations make the sane choice that `>>` of a signed integer type is an arithmetic right shift.  ISO C requires that implementations define which it is, but unfortunately leaves them the choice of logical or arithmetic.  (Unlike signed left shift, it can't be UB).

But fortunately your code is written in GNU C (not ISO C), e.g. using `__attribute__((packed))` on a struct.  **[GNU C guarantees that `>>` on signed integers is arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc//Integers-implementation.html)**.  (And that signed integer types are 2's complement!)  So the only implementations that can compile your code are ones where `>>` on an `int` does what you want.

> [(GCC manual, integer implementation-defined behaviour)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc//Integers-implementation.html):
>   Signed ‘>>’ acts on negative numbers by sign extension.

You might want to use unsigned bitfield members and unsigned arithmetic for bias/unbias.  But you can safely use `int32_t` (which is guaranteed to be a 2's complement integer type), or just `int` for the temporary holding the field value for the bias/unbias calculations.  Bias/unbias may cross zero (unsigned wrapping), not signed overflow.

---

### Or better, use @Rainer P's method:

Don't unbias first, just unsigned shift and then add half the bias constant.  (See his answer for how it simplifies down to that).  Doing the shift before unbiasing means the exponent is unsigned so shifting in a zero is good.  (I think this works right even for tiny values with biased-exponents near zero, i.e. near the smallest possible exponent encoding).

I tried a few values on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, manually shifting the exponent and then adding 1 (with carry) to the 2nd-highest exponent bit.  e.g. `2.3509887E-38` (biased exponent = `0b0000'0010`) becomes 2.1684043E-19 (biased exponent = `0b0100'0001`).

But beware when shifting the entire bit-pattern that you don't shift in a `1` from the sign bit of `-0.0`.  You are handling `a == 0.0` as a special case so you're fine there because `-0.0 == 0.0` is true.  I guess you can't let `0.0` go through the main NR loop because you'd have a division by zero.

---

Footnote 1:

IDK why you'd choose `unsigned short` instead of just `unsigned` for your exponent bitfield type.  The underlying type of a bitfield can be wider  than the field without hurting anything, and some compilers will do math at the width of that type.  So using `unsigned int` if it's wide enough is a good idea.  `int` is at least 16 bits.

Using `uint64_t` as the bitfield type can result in slow 32-bit code with some compilers (notably MSVC), but I think `unsigned int` is always fine for the exponent.  Unsigned does make sense for the biased exponent.

Fun fact: just `int` as the bitfield type leaves the signedness up to the implementation.  You can use `signed int` to force signed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527387/signed-bit-field-represetation

---

#### unroll instead of checking `c % 2 == 0`

A compiler might do this anyway, but it probably makes more sense to just unroll your loop by 2 instead of using a counter to do something special every other iteration.

The actual Newton iteration expression is compact enough that repeating it once is probably *more* simple for humans to read than working through the `c++` and `if (c%2 == 0)` logic.

You can handle the `while(foo)` condition as `if(!foo) break;` when unrolling, or simply leave it out and only check for leaving the loop every 2 Newton iterations, unless you need to check both possibilities to catch alternation between two values.

(With a bad initial estimate that will take many iterations anyway, this might be worth it.  Otherwise probably not, especially on a superscalar / out-of-order CPU that can be checking the branch condition in parallel with the main dependency chain which doesn't have a lot of ILP (instruction-level parallelism); mostly one long dependency chain.)

---

### Pull some checks off the fast-path

Your version has 4 separate checks on `a` before we reach the actual work.

```
    if(a < -(TYPE)0)
    {
        errno = EDOM;
        return NAME_SFX(nan)("");
    }
    if(a == (TYPE)0 || is_nan(a) || a > TYPE_MAX)
    {
        return a;
    }
```

Instead, **catch the special cases with one or two compares, and sort them out in that block, off the fast path**.  The performance of `sqrt(NaN)` is much much less important than the performance of `sqrt(1.234)`

```
    if(! a > (TYPE)0)
    {
        if(a == (TYPE)0 || is_nan(a))
            return a;
        // else a < 0
        errno = EDOM;
        return NAME_SFX(nan)("");
    }
    if( a > TYPE_MAX)
    {
        return a;
    }
```

If you need to handle subnormals specially (at least for generating the initial approximation?), you might use `if (! a>=DBL_MIN)`.  Or you could decide that your soft-float implementation simply doesn't handle subnormals.

IDK what your goal is with this code; if it was part of a soft-float library, simply using FP add, mul, and divide seems inefficient.  You'd want to optimize multiple operations together and so on.

But if it's for HW FPUs, then I think real all FPUs will have sqrt built-in as well.

So I assume this is just a learning exercise.  So we won't get into too detail of optimizing it for any particular hardware or compiler.

Comment: You can't have a bitfield with a size wider than the size of the type.

Comment: @JL2210: I know you can't have `int a:64`, that's why I said the underlying type can be *wider* (than the field) without causing a problem, not vice versa.  Apparently my wording is easy to misread, will think about how to fix.

Comment: You said *"Using `uint64_t` as the bitfield type can result in slow 32-bit code [...], but I think `unsigned int` is always fine"*

Comment: @JL2210: Oh.  I meant always fine *for the exponent* where you were previously using `unsigned short`.  Because both types have the same minimum width in ISO C.  I meant that using `uint64_t e:8` could give slower-than-necessary code for the exponent.  Specifically with MSVC, I was remembering writing this answer: [Unresolved external symbol \_\_aullshr when optimization is turned off](//stackoverflow.com/q/54719855)

Comment: Please read my code again. It checks if `a == 0` and `return`s `a` if so. Also read the POSIX spec for the function.

Comment: @JL2210: Oh yes, I missed that you check separately for `== 0.0`.  I was assuming that you would just use one check on the fast-path to exclude both negative an NaN inputs by requiring that `x >= 0.0`.  That's false for NaN so you can move the `isnan` check inside an `if` that won't run for the fast-path.  So you can do `if (! x>0.0) { further checks to detect +=0.0, NaN, or negative }`

Comment: @JL2210: Updated my answer to fix that mistake you pointed out, and talk about some of the stuff I've said in comments.  And more.

Comment: This actually isn't a learning exercise. This will be the fallback for the `libm` in my C library. The assembly will take longer, but first I want to check for accurate results. I also know how Intel is when it comes to accuracy in this type of thing.

Comment: @JL22: Like I said at the top of my answer, `sqrt` is *required* by IEEE to be correctly-rounded, just like + - * and /. All x86 sqrt instructions do that.  (Except of course `rsqrtps` which intentionally gives a fast approximation of 1/sqrt(x)).  Intel's *compiler* enables fast-math by default (unlike GCC), but Intel's HW is IEEE-compliant. Perhaps you're thinking of instructions like `fsin`, which *aren't* required to be correctly rounded and which in practice have huge relative error near Pi/2. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion

Comment: (And I'm terribly unfamiliar with SIMD instructions.)

Comment: @JL2210 If it helps, there's a scalar [`rsqrtss`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rsqrtss) which is what you'd actually use if you were considering using `x * newton(approx_rsqrt(x))` as the implementation here.  But of course if you were using Intel intrinsics, you'd just use `_mm_sqrt_sd` or `_mm_sqrt_ss` after converting a scalar to a `__m128d` or `__m128` vector (with the low element being the only one you care about).

Comment: @JL2210: Possibly you could get away with using GNU C `__builtin_sqrt(x)` if you compile with -fno-math-errno.  But that could emit a call to the `sqrt()` function if it decides not to inline it, so it only works on targets where GCC can inline it, and with optimization enabled.  I'm not sure if there's a good way to get GCC to do this for you on every ISA it knows how to handle, instead of writing asm by hand for each platform for the libm `sqrt` implementation.  You should def. do that for every major one, though, like `sqrtsd xmm0,xmm0` / `ret` for x86-64.

Comment: Ugh, Intel syntax..

Comment: @JL2210: What, you *like* AT&T syntax?  It's trivial to translate this case, but maybe `sqrtsd %xmm0, %xmm0` ; `ret` makes you happier?  Or `sqrtss` for the `float` case, of course.  And `fldt 8(%rsp)` ; `fsqrt` ; ret for the `long double` case in ABIs where `long double` is 80-bit float, unlike Windows where it's the same as `double`.

Comment: :P Thanks. I understand why some people like Intel syntax, but it just seems backwards to me (probably because I used to read GCC's output before I knew about the option to change the syntax). By now, it's a habit.

Comment: @JL2210: I used to like AT&T syntax because its addressing-mode syntax mirrored the machine encoding, making it clearer which component was which.  But once I started reading Intel's manuals to look up how instructions worked, mentally translating to AT&T became extra work.  Also, destination on the left is like C, so you can scan down the justified column of operands and find insns that modify a given register, vs. the ragged ends of lines having the destination in AT&T.  Actually typing the `%` and `$` decorations is a pain, too.  Not to mention AT&T's x87 design bug (fsubr vs. fsub etc.)

Comment: @JL2210: Anyway, unlike some people I don't hate AT&T syntax.  Many more people dislike AT&T syntax than dislike Intel syntax, I think.  Or they're more likely to be vocal about it.  It only takes me a minute to mentally change gears and think in AT&T.  But most still-relevant ISAs have destination on the left in their standard syntax, unlike AT&T, PDP-11 and m68k.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see why you define this constant yourself:

> ```
> #define MANTISSA_SIZE 52
> ```

Given we already assume that `FLT_RADIX` is 2, we can use the appropriate macro from `<float.h>` (`DBL_MANT_DIG` for `double`, etc.).

---

I think there's danger of integer overflow here:

> ```
> /* Divide the exponent by 2 */
> r.o.e -= EXPONENT_BIAS;
> r.o.e = (r.o.e & 1) | (r.o.e >> 1);
> r.o.e += EXPONENT_BIAS;
> ```

We'd be better extracting into a big enough temporary, and applying the exponent bias to that:

```
int e = r.o.e - EXPONENT_BIAS;
e = (e & 1) | (e >> 1);
r.o.e = e + EXPONENT_BIAS;
```

It might be possible to shift in place and then correct using half the bias; I haven't checked whether that's equivalent.

Comment: Signed bit-shifting isn't well-defined. I don't think the second half of your answer is valid.

Comment: I agree with the top point, but it would be `DBL_MANT_DIG-1`, not `DBL_MANT_DIG`.

Comment: @JL2210: Is right-shifting a signed bitfield any better defined than a signed `int`?  Doesn't your current code still rely on `>>` being an arithmetic right shift that shifts in `1`s for negative exponents? Yes it's implementation-defined whether it's arithmetic or logical (not undefined).  However your code uses GNU C `__attribute__((packed))` so you actually *can* rely on arithmetic right shift if you're intentionally writing in GNU C, not ISO C.  https://gnu.huihoo.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.4/gcc/Integers-implementation.html specifies that "Signed ‘>>’ acts on negative numbers by sign extension."

Comment: @PeterCordes My bitfields aren't signed. Take a look at the `typedef`s.

Comment: @JL2210: Yeah, just noticed that.  I assumed they would be signed because unsigned right-shift of the 2's complement exponent (after unbiasing) doesn't make sense, does it?  A negative exponent (small magnitude float) becomes a very large positive exponent (close-ish to DBL_MAX) after your logical right shift of the exponent field.  Or am I missing something and your function does work correctly for inputs like `0.0001`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, you're right. I get absurd output with small inputs on the original.

Comment: @JL2210: Hardware that reads the float will effectively undo the bias.  It's just an encoding method; the real *value* is a 2's complement integer.  That's what you're working with after undoing the bias (decoding).  Yes you have to redo the encoding to make it an IEEE float again, but so what?  BTW, if you were to logical right-shift without undoing the bias first, you'd make values twice as close to the smallest possible exponent value instead of twice as close to the middle value (0 after bias).  So `1.0f` would become `1e-17f` or something, if FLT_MIN is about 1e-34f.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99070/discussion-between-jl2210-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 4):

### Modular odd check

The compiler is likely to do this anyway, but can't

```
if(c % 2 == 0)
```

be

```
if (!(c & 1))
```

?

### Factoring

Isn't

```
r.f -= (r.f*r.f-a)/(2*r.f);
```

equivalent to:

```
r.f = (r.f + a/r.f)/2?
```

### Optimization

Depending on which compiler you're using and what flags you pass it, some of your attempted math risks modification by the optimizer, and in an implementation so closely coupled to the hardware, this might matter. Have you checked your produced assembly? Can you show us your build flags?

Comment: Under **Factoring**: That's Newton-Raphson, it detects the amount of error and decreases it. It's not the same as `(1-a)/2`.

Comment: Do you mind if I make an edit to the question showing how the code was before I preprocessed it?

Comment: Soooo. The problem isn't with my answer (and I don't think it should receive your edit, yet); it's with the code you posted. A strict interpretation of the CR policies would suggest that since there's already an answer, you can't edit your code. However, I think instead that you should edit your question to show your actual (non-preprocessed) code, and I'll then amend this answer myself.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks. I've added a clarification.

Comment: Re. factoring: So my first stab at the math was wrong, and I modified it to reflect reality.

Comment: The second has two divisions while the first has one.

Comment: Produced assembly seems fine, GCC with optimization levels three and size.

Comment: The division increase would usually be a concern, but in this case the `/2` should be converted to a `>>1`, which is cheap.

Comment: You can't do bitshifts on floating-point numbers.

Comment: Ah, but you can! You're already assuming that you're coupled to the IEEE754 implementation, so while a blind `>>1` won't work, you can decrement the exponent directly.

Comment: The compiler does automatically do the modular odd check.

Comment: `r.f = (r.f + a/r.f)/2` can be further simplified to `r.f += a/r.f; r.o.e--;`

Comment: @JL2210: `flt / 2` will reliably optimize to `flt * 0.5` because `1/2.0` is exactly representable.  (`-ffast-math` is only needed to optimize division by constants that don't have exact reciprocals). So it's still just one division, with one fewer multiplication than the original. Or yes in theory a compiler could optimize it to a decrement of the exponent field, but it's not safe without checking for underflow so compilers definitely won't.  Multiply by 0.5 is very efficient. (On x86/SSE2 it is possible to do it efficiently do integer math between FP ops, with only bypass-forwarding latency.)

Comment: @JL: Optimizing `if(c % 2 == 0)`  to `c&1` isn't particularly useful, compilers already know how to do this.  (Even though `c` is signed, comparing the `%` result against `0` means the optimization is still possible).  More useful would be unrolling the source by a factor of 2 instead of conditionally doing something every other iteration.  That's what you want the compiler to do anyway.  (Use an `if(!something)break`  to replace the `while(something)` loop condition, or just let it always do an even number of Newton iterations if that might be more efficient than an extra check.)

Comment: @JL: or really, making the iteration count a compile-time constant so it can be fully unrolled makes a lot of sense, if your initial approximation can be accurate enough for every possible case.  (Like in @ Rainer P's answer).

Comment: I immediately know what `if(c % 2 == 0)` does, but I have to think multiple times to figure out what `if (!(c & 1))` does. That's premature optimization and IMHO violates clean code rules (KISS).